# How to make the Job history server to save the job's stdout?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a standard configured HDP 2.2 environment with a Job History service. Once I restart the YARN services all the logs seems to disappear from the Resource Manager.

I do have older logs in the Job History server, but the stdout stream seems to be missing.

How can I retain it?